How can you prevent the holding down of a key in python turtle?
I am trying to make a game with 2 turtles that move in python turtle. I have used the onkey() command tomake the turtles move. I want to make them move at the same time because the game is kind of like a race but when ever you hold down a key, the other turtle stops moving and this gives an unfair advantage. Here is the code used for moving the turtle
screen.onkey(p1_up, 'w')
screen.onkey(p1_down, 's')
screen.onkey(p1_left, 'a')
screen.onkey(p1_right, 'd')
screen.listen()

screen.onkey(p2_up, 'Up')
screen.onkey(p2_down, 'Down')
screen.onkey(p2_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(p2_right, 'Right')
screen.listen()

and here is an example of a function if it may help
def p1_left():
  p1.setheading(180)
  p1.forward(20)
  p1.check_collision()
  p1.check_victory()

I want to make it so that if you hold down any of the keys, the turtle either moves only one step or just doesn't move. I am new to coding so I haven't tried anything except for using onkeypress() and the onkeyrelease() commands. This question may be similar to How to bind several key presses together in turtle graphics however the answers there did not help as those helped bind 2 presses to make another function but here I want to make both turtles move simultaneously and I have tried a few other ways but this is the next option on my list.

This question is similar to: How to bind several key presses together in turtle graphics?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can write custom functions where you define the behaviour as you described it in your question. To acheive that behaviour you can use flags.
p1LeftStatus = False

def p1_left():
    global p1LeftStatus

    if not p1LeftStatus:
       "Your code goes here"
        p1LeftStatus = True

 def p1_left_released():
   global p1LeftStatus
   p1LeftStatus = False

When the key is pressed: a function is called which sets the flag to True. When the key is released: the status is reset. This will make sure that the turtle can only move once per keystroke even if the key is held down.
I hope this answers your question.
